# {TypeError} '<=' not supported between instances of 'CombinedExpression' and 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to filter my model using specific criteria. For instance, I only want to retrieve records for teams that have expired after 7 days. Here's my Django query:

```
current_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()

MyModel.objects.filter(
                Q(end_date__lt=current_date) &
                Q(locked=False) &
                Q(F('end_date') + datetime.timedelta(days=7) <= current_date)
            ).values('id')
```

My model has a end_date field of type DateField. However, when I execute the code, I receive a TypeError with the message "'<=' not supported between instances of 'CombinedExpression' and 'datetime.date'".

I've tried several solutions that I found on the web, such as using the Cast operator and Expression Wrapper, but none of them seem to work. Here's my latest attempt:

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here my last trial:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q(end_date__lt=current_date) &
    Q(locked=False) &
    Q(Cast(F('end_date') + timezone.timedelta(days=7), output_field=models.DateField()) <= current_date)
).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do math on the kwargs of that function. Notice how in the first Q, you have:

```
end_date__lt=current_date
```

That is a kwarg that you are sending to the method. While in the last, you have:

```
F('end_date') + timezone.timedelta(days=7) <= current_date
```

Notice how the syntax of those two is different?
What you're looking for is something like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
Q(end_date__lte=(current_date + timedelta(days=7)))
```